# Python Regex 'not' to identify pattern within <a></a>

Tags: python, regex, hyperlink, regex-negation

I am dealing a problem to write a python regex 'not'to identify a certain pattern within  href  tags.

My aim is to replace all occurrences of DSS[a-z]{2}[0-9]{2} with a href link as shown below,but without replacing the same pattern occurring inside href tags

Present Regex:

```
replaced = re.sub("[^http://*/s](DSS[a-z]{2}[0-9]{2})", "<a href=\"http://test.com=\\1\">\\1</a>", input)
```

I need to add this new regex using an OR operator to the existing one I have

**EDIT:**

**I am trying to use regex just for a simple operation. I want to replace the occurrences of the pattern anywhere in the html using a regex except occurring within`<a><\a>`.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Find & Replace Beautiful Soup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674310/python-find-replace-beautiful-soup)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with `[^http://*/s]`? This isn't making any sense.

Comment: I am trying not to match the pattern when it is inside a http:// link

Comment: @thinkcool: Regexes cannot reliably do this, even if you think it's a simple operation. People won't tell you how to do it with regex, because regex is not the right tool for the job. It gets asked again and again, which is why e-satis linked a standard answer. If you're handling HTML, use an HTML parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to any question having regexp and HTML in the same sentence is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

In Python, the best HTML parser is indeed [Beautilf Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html).

If you want to persist with regexp, you can try a [negative lookbehind](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) to avoid anything precessed by a `"`. At your own risk.

Comment: Well.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string/4234491#4234491

Comment: Lol. Funny, but let's save that for regex master with very special edge cases.